# INDEX/MATCH of MAX of a sum/difference

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Hello everybody and sorry for my English but I'm not a native speaker.

I have a database that is already full of data and I would like to save the time to create another column only for a basic operation.

What I would like to do is to a find a way to calculate the max difference between 2 columns [for example Revenues for 2013 and Revenues for 2011] and then have the product written in another cell.

The database is structured like this.

```
1. Product1 - Revenues for 2013 - Revenues for 2012 - Revenues for 2011
2. Product2 - Revenues For 2013 - Revenues for 2012 - Revenues for 2011

="The product that has grown the most during the last 2 years is"&FORMULA&
```

I thought that I could make it with a `INDEX/MATCH` function combined with a `MAX` of the difference between the two values in the `MATCH` part, but it does not work since there is no reference in the matrix for the values.

This is why I'm asking for help, since there must be a solution but I couldn't find it online.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By Adding new Column:**

Easiest way will be to create a a difference column and use index match and max function together like this:

```
=INDEX(A2:E4,MATCH(MAX(E2:E4),E2:E4,0),1)
```

[image]

**Without Adding new Columns:**

if you don't want to create new column. then replace Max(E2:E4) part with MAX(B2:B5-D2:D5)  in above formula and confirm with **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER** not just ENTER... you will see { } brackets appear. See below:

```
 {=INDEX(A2:D5,MATCH(MAX(B2:B5-D2:D5),B2:B5-D2:D5,0),1)}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kashif, I wondered if it was possible to do so without creating a new column since this operation would be done for several sheets and several times in each one of them but it seems there are no viable options :) thanks for your insight anyway!

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how it is done without creating new columns. if it is solved. Please accept this as your preferred answer

Comment: Works like a charm, apparently I must study these array functions a lot more! Thanks again

Comment: +1 Check Chip Pearson's site for a [nice explanation of array formulas](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx) (and just about everything else in Excel)>